# Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to write a code for a search bar in Swift on (Xcode):

```
    @IBOutlet weak var searchPost: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tbvPost: UITableView!

    var posts = [Post]()
    var filteredPosts = [Post]()

extension PostViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if searchPost.text != "" {
            return self.filteredPosts.count
        }

        return self.posts.count
    }


if searchPost.text != "" {
```

and  i am getting this error for that line:

```
Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: With that little code it's hard.. but did you verify if `searchPost` is nil?

Comment: That's an assertion failure, and means that you're accessing or force-unwrapping a nil value, or comparing incompatible value types.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `searchPost` is `nil` because you have never hooked up a search bar from the storyboard to this outlet.

Answer (score -1):

you should fix it by testing for nil instead of an empty string 
like

```
if searchPost?.text != nil{ 
// do your stuff here or in an else statement 
}
```

Comment: as the first comment says with that little of code it is hard for us to replicate what you are trying to do please update your question to include more info if you want good help

Comment: It should be `searchPost?.text != nil` to avoid having the same crash if `searchPost` is `nil`.

Comment: ok so I am still not completely sure what you are trying to do, Although it looks like you are trying to filter an array based on the `UISearchBar` and both variables `post` and `filteredPost` are equal to the same thing from the looks of your code and you are returning basically the same `Int` and yes @NRitH is correct you need to unwrap the value with ? I edited my answer.

Comment: NRitH Thank you man because of that change make the error actually disappear. eventhough the list of posts is not showing neither the search function works. instead, i get spinning wheel. I wonder if there's another error in the same code!

Comment: @DjangoGuy have you set the datasource up for your table view yet in the function `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {}` if not it is going to show up empty